# Making two axes, with each their units, for the same data

Tags: flot

It is best explained by the example below (my use is plotting total electricity use on one axis, and electricity use per capita on the other).

[image]

So I want to plot some data according to one axis ( the left axis). But for the reader I want to supply an alternative unit for the same data (on the right axis). There is a linear relation between the two axes.

Is that possible with the jQuery flot library?

Answer (score 3):

If the relationship is linear, than setting intelligent min/max values should be all you need to do.  In your example above `1 mph = 1.60934 km/h`, so just do:

```
    yaxes: [ 
        { 
            //mph axis 
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        }, 
        {
            //kph axis
            min: 0,
            max: 100 * 1.60934,
            position: 'right'
        } 
    ]
```

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PGxBQ/).